# Application not terminating after processing a notification action

Tags: swift, push-notification, completionhandler, unusernotificationcenter

Using the `func userNotificationCenter( _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void )` function, I am utilizing the response to process a notification with an action and I am running into some odd behavior when the application is fully killed prior. Following all of the work that needs to be completed, I make sure to call the completionHandler at the right time. This works as expected, but I am trying to understand why does the application continue to run?

While the application may not show as running after the work is completed and completionHandler() is called, it is evident that it is still running as when I go to open it, it picks back up from my dashboard screen and has all the data already loaded. Since the app was killed prior to performing the notification action, I expect the app to be killed/terminated after calling completionHandler(). This way after opening it up normally, it should start from the beginning. Why does the app continue to run in this case?